# Twitter bootstrap modal popup form - how to lower the displayed form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have recently downloaded TB 2, and have started to familiarize myself with it. I am creating a page based on the hero example.

I have added a popup form to the page, using code I found [here](http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/modals-tutorial.php). It all seems to work so far - however, I feel that the displayed popup box is too high up. I would like to lower it a bit, so that I can (at least), see the top of the displayed form.

I used firebug to check out the css. I noticed the styling is coming from bootstrap, from these lines (in order given):

```
element.style {
    display: block;
}
.modal.fade.in {
    top: 50%;
}
.modal.fade {
    top: -25%;
    transition: opacity 0.3s linear 0s, top 0.3s ease-out 0s;
}
.fade.in {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.modal {
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    left: 50%;
    margin: -250px 0 0 -280px;
    outline: 0 none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    width: 560px;
    z-index: 1050;
}
.fade {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s;
}
```

The "obvious" thing to do would be to add a selector to the element that displays the form and add a new CSS rule to my external stylesheet, or perhaps override/customize a style provided by TB.

HOWEVER, since I don't really know what I'm doing (I'm still learning TB), I thought it best to ask in here in case I ended up breaking the layout I have so far.

What is the recommended way of lowering the popped up form so that I can see the top part of the form, and perhaps a little bit of the Navbar behind it (ideally, though, I would like the popup form to be shown underneath the navbar menu - but that may be too complicated).

Answer (score 3):

Don't be afraid to tinker the code.
Just take your own rules and showe them at the bottom.
You can always remove it later.
Don't edit bootstrap css code itself.
The lowest code overrides the previous.

And use firebug & it's style & computed style panels to test.